# jquery datepicker ui-state-default ui-state-hover href="#"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spring-security

I'm having an issue with my jquery datepicker.

Whenever I click on a the datepicker the datepicker appears fine and I can select a date. The issue I have is that when I select a date the following link is executed.

```
http://myServer:8080/MyApp/#
```

I was interested so I used firebug to inspect the generated styles and I can see that there is in fact this link on all of my dates in the jquery datepicker.

Does anyone know what I need to do to change this? I'm posting the javascript behind my form and also a screenshot of the generated styles.

```
FORM ELEMENTS ...
<div class="ym-fbox" id="weekEndingDate">
    <form:label path="weekEndingDate"><spring:message code="label.weekEndingDate"/><sup class="ym-required">*</sup></form:label>
    <form:input path="weekEndingDate" class="{required:true} datepicker" placeholder="enter a value"/>
</div>

JS BEHIND FORM ...
$().ready(function() {

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
    $(".datepicker").blur(function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });

    $("#submitBtn").click(function(){ 
        if ($("shortsAndOversDailyForm").valid()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

[image]

thanks

**Update 20140110**

The versions of jquery I am using are ...

```
jquery-1.7.1.min.js
jquery.metadata.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.hotkeys-0.8.js
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
jquery.ui.datepicker-en-AU.js
jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js
```

I am using these versions of jquery because I copied another application at my company that uses the same versions. I did that because I need to support ie6 and those versions of jquery work well in ie6. (This is probably another question worth another post however do you guys think I am using the right versions? Or should I go for newer versions?)

I spent another couple of hours trying to fix this problem this morning and came across the following...

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-to-ie-jquery-date-picker-jumps-to-top-of-page

I tried to get this working for me by adding the following function to my js...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: function() {
          alert("on select");
          $(".ui-datepicker a").removeAttr("href");
          $(this).change();
      }
    });
```

But I can't get the onSelect function to fire. for me so it doesn't work.

Comment: The datepicker has a click handler on the elements, so they don't follow the link. What problem are you having because of this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it properly . The problem is that I keep getting sent back to my login page. I think my spring security module is intercepting the link. Is there a way I can get rid if the href?

Comment: I've added spring-security to the tags, maybe someone who knows about that will be able to help.

Comment: There can be id issues of form elements.

Comment: Id issues on form elements? What do you mean ?

Comment: I guess if it's turned into a spring security question. The question should be how can I add an exception for a hyperlink of #. I'll see if I can look at my logs to check for a 403

Answer (score 1):

in Datepicker the click event is attached to <td> tag, which is the parent of <a> tag.

This event handler return false to jQuery.

Then jQuery calls event.preventDefault() and stopPropagation().

That's how they prevent the default action of <a> tag.

So you should not get the /MyApp/# link triggered.

What's the jQuery version are you using? (Now jQuery UI is using 1.9.1)

Did you attached any other event handler to the <a> tag?

What is the element that you used to show the datepicker?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm struggling. Just spent another couple of hours on it unsuccessfully trying to fix. I am updating my original post to have versions and also to show a possible solution which I can't seem to get to work for me.

Comment: The onSelect function should be fired... And this should work... Did anyone changed the jQuery ui library? How about this lib? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by doing the following...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: false,
      onSelect: function() {
          $("#"+$(this).attr("data-target")).val( $(this).val());
      }
    });


@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));
}
```